# How to fix col-md issue on tablet not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

On Full Screen & mobile the ranges panel (class="col-md-3") displays correctly but on tablet the left column is covered by the youtube image panel (class="col-12 col-md-9").

I have tried multiple configurations for the div style but don't know enough about Bootstrap css to fix. Any help will be greatly appreciated. www.topjocks.co.za/saddler/

As in full screen the left ranges panel shouldn't be hidden behind youtube image.

Comment: First glance it looks like `col-md-3` isn't large enough to fit that background image you're using

Answer (score 1):

Your Range Image is longer than the col-md-3 when it's on tablet mode. That's why it hide the right part of the image.

Solution.
You can adjust the col-md-3 to col-md-5 and change the youtube div to col-md-7.

Comment: Thanks, Tried that but that doesn't fix :( its places them below each other.

Comment: You put two class that's why it's not working 
`<div class="class=" col-12 col-md-7 col-lg-9"></div>` 
Make it like this.
`<div class="col-12 col-md-7 col-lg-9">
</div>`.

Comment: You sir are a Legend! Thanks so much!! Working till 3 am not so clever :)

Comment: hehe. Just Accept my Answer. It will really help me out :)

Comment: Done, thanks again! One more question. The social media icons on the footer how can I change css to make the icon in centre of circle? Tried a few padding things but didn't win.. is there a trick? When I'm finished this project I am going to learn C# and do a bootstrap course.

Comment: To center the icon. Add `position: relative;` to a tag. 
After that add this `position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to the icon. You can check it here [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_center-vertical.asp). What I mean in Accept my answer is to vote my answer hehe.

Answer (score 1):

Using the appropriate bootstrap grid system will help in this case, since the image you are using is longer it will be better to use the right column classes for the different screen sizes

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3">
</div>

<div class="class="col-12 col-md-7 col-lg-9"">
</div>
```

This will help with the tablet issue on your website.
For more information on grid systems
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

Comment: Thanks Richard but that doesn't fix :( its places them below each other.